# How to combine python multiprocessing and pipeline technique?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pipeline

Hello I'm new here and I want to ask some question.Now I'm using python multiprocessing to process data in queue. Example I have 3 functions to calculate data from queue and in queue I have 3 datas. Is it possible to use pipeline technique with multiprocessing to make it more faster?

In this code I tried to use multiprocessing queue to communicate between multiprocessing process and use Lock to prevent other process to use data in queue before it done from previous function. but it

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process, cpu_count, Queue, Pool, Lock, Array
from threading import Thread, current_thread
import time
import os

def a(pid, q1, q2, lock):
    while not q1.empty():
        data = q1.get()
        print("data from q1 is %s" % data)
        # for i in range(1000000):
        new_data = data*2
        lock.acquire()
        q2.put(new_data)
        print(pid)
        lock.release()

def b(pid, q2, q3, lock):
    while not q2.empty():
        data = q2.get()
        print("data from q2 is %s" % data)
        # for i in range(1000000):
        lock.acquire()
        new_data = data*3
        q3.put(new_data)
        print(pid)
        lock.release()

def c(pid, q3, q4, lock):
    while not q3.empty():
        data = q3.get()
        print("data from q3 is %s" % data)
        # for i in range(1000000):
        lock.acquire()
        new_data = data*4
        q4.put(new_data)
        print(pid)
        lock.release()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    number = [1,2,3]

    lock = Lock()

    q1 = Queue()
    q2 = Queue()
    q3 = Queue()
    q4 = Queue()

    for data in number:
        q1.put(data)

    p1 = Process(target=a,args=(1, q1, q2, lock))
    p2 = Process(target=b,args=(2, q2, q3, lock))
    p3 = Process(target=c,args=(3, q3, q4, lock))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()

    p1.join()   
    p2.join()
    p3.join()

    for i in range(q4.qsize()):
        print(q4.get())
```

I expect that the sequence of pipeline should be execute like this f1 | f1 f2 | f1 f2 f3 | f2 f3 | f3 and solution in queue is 24, 48, 72 if my information is correct. I try my best to explain how the things should work because this is my first time to ask something in stackoverflow and my english skill is not good and also I really need help.

Comment: Please tell us what you have already tried and what results you have achieved.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using `q.empty()` to terminate your loops. Some of those `Queues` will be empty at the start, and those `Process` will terminate too early. You need a different technique to let the `p2` and `p3` processes know when to quit.

Here is a modification of your code that uses `None` as a flag in the queues to signal when done:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process, cpu_count, Queue, Pool, Lock, Array
from threading import Thread, current_thread
import time
import os

def a(pid, q1, q2, lock):
    while not q1.empty():
        data = q1.get()
        print("data from q1 is %s" % data)
        # for i in range(1000000):
        new_data = data*2
        lock.acquire()
        q2.put(new_data)
        print(pid)
        lock.release()
    q2.put(None)

def b(pid, q2, q3, lock):
    while True:
        data = q2.get()
        if data is None:
            q3.put(None)
            return
        print("data from q2 is %s" % data)
        # for i in range(1000000):
        lock.acquire()
        new_data = data*3
        q3.put(new_data)
        print(pid)
        lock.release()

def c(pid, q3, q4, lock):
    while True:
        data = q3.get()
        if data is None:
            return
        print("data from q3 is %s" % data)
        # for i in range(1000000):
        lock.acquire()
        new_data = data*4
        q4.put(new_data)
        print(pid)
        lock.release()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    number = [1,2,3]

    lock = Lock()

    q1 = Queue()
    q2 = Queue()
    q3 = Queue()
    q4 = Queue()

    for data in number:
        q1.put(data)

    p1 = Process(target=a,args=(1, q1, q2, lock))
    p2 = Process(target=b,args=(2, q2, q3, lock))
    p3 = Process(target=c,args=(3, q3, q4, lock))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()

    for i in range(q4.qsize()):
        print(q4.get())
```

Also, you don't actually need the `Lock`. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/queue.html):

> The queue module implements multi-producer, multi-consumer queues. It
>   is especially useful in threaded programming when information must be
>   exchanged safely between multiple threads. The Queue class in this
>   module implements all the required locking semantics.